# PhoneGap - Can't hide Android splash screen

Tags: android, cordova

I'm able to display a splash screen in Android using PhoneGap 3.3.0 and it works when I set it to automatically time out at 10 seconds. But when I use `navigator.splashscreen.hide()` to hide the splash screen in my javascript (according to the docs) it throws a `uncaught type error: splashscreen is not defined`.

I just upgraded to PhoneGap 3.3.0.  I verified that I do have the splashscreen installed and is reflected in my res/xml/config.xml. I am building locally.

```
$('#mainPage').bind('pageinit', onDeviceReady);

function onDeviceReady() {
mainInit();
optimizeSpeed();
adjustScale();
displayLastFeeding();

navigator.splashscreen.hide();
console.log("device ready");
}
```

This is taken straight from the docs, so not sure what is going on here...

EDIT:
Modifying the above code to use the deviceready event still has the same error (navigator.splashscreen not defined).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
});
```

I include phonegap.js and cordova.js in my index.html file.

Comment: navigator is available after deviceready event is called, try binding your function to that event

Comment: Tried that too, I can bind to the deviceready event and execute other functions, but get the same error that navigator.splashscreen is undefined.

Comment: Update: `device` isn't defined either, even though I have the plugin installed and have done some reinstalls. Thus issue is not specific to splashscreen plugin.